# What are some possible causes of program crashing when returning a value?

Tags: c++, crash, return

I have a bunch of code roughly equivalent to this:

```
bool test(double e, short a, short b, short c) {
    // Things being calculated here...
    cout << "debug_3" << endl;
    return (1 - abs(cos_th)) < (1 - cos(e));

}

int main() {

// something...

 cout << "debug_0" << endl;
        if(test(e,1,2,0)) {
            cout << "debug_4" << endl;
            // Bunch of useful operations...
        }

// something...

}
```

Running the code generates the output:

```
debug_3
```

After which the program crashes (displaying "The program has stopped working..." in Windows). I have never encountered crashing at value return and I don't know what causes it or how I could fix it. Any thoughts on the issue?

EDIT: Some more info:

In my builds I also verify that the values of `cos_th` and `e` are valid.

People seem to point to the second something as the source of problems but my problem seems resolved (i.e. no crashes) when I get rid of the if-statement with a call to `test()`...

Comment: You may have to blame the "something..." part. What is `system` and how do you initialize it?

Comment: try changing your cout to cerr when you do printf-style debugging (cerr is flushed). Otherwise use a debugger to know where exactly your code crashes.

Comment: For starters, I'd put cos_th and e to cout at debug_3. If they are something like NaN or inf, not sure how abs and cos are supposed to behave!

Comment: Maybe  the value of `e` or `cos_th` is `nan`.

Comment: I would bet on second `//something...`

Comment: "I have never encountered crashing at value return" - and I don't see any proof that this is happening. From all I can see, most logical explanation is that `aligned` returns `false`, you continue to second `//something` part and something crashes there.

Comment: as Zdeslav implies, if aligned returns `false` `cout << "debug_4" << endl;` is never reached, and thus your programm crashes without you ever seeing `debug4` eventhough the crash might happen in something. Put another debug output after the `if`. Or try using your debugger and stepping through the program

Answer (score 0):

The only things we can fix without knowing what `system` is, is to change the type of `a` `b` and `c` to `unsigned short` since they are just array indexes, and make sure they are within array bounds. You might also need to make sure this is not zero since you divide by the result:

```
sqrt((Xca*Xca+Yca*Yca+Zca*Zca)*(Xba*Xba+Yba*Yba+Zba*Zba))
```

Use `cerr` instead of `cout` to make sure the output is flushed but you still don't see `debug 4`.

Put more output inside an else condition or after the `if`: maybe the function returns false?

If you can't locate the error precisely, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Crash at return usually means that your function overwrites stack (and thus the return address) and your program jumps to nowhere. You can verify this by stepping instruction by instruction at the disassembly level.

Comment: In this case, the function only writes to 6 local variables and does not write to any dereferenced location, i don't think it is causing any stack error. My guess would be either segmentation fault from the array accesses or a divide by zero exception.